# Does the latest version of Python have libraries for easy host/server connections?

Tags: multiplayer, python, pygame, client-server, hosting

We're working on a turn-based multiplayer Risk-type strategy game in Pygame, and I was wondering if there were any pre-existing libraries like PodSixNet that worked for Python versions 3 and up that would help with establishing host/client server connections. Does anything like that exist, or do the latest versions of Python/Pygame already have functions or libraries that would help with this sort of thing?

Comment: Host/server connections are not specific to game development. And which technology to use questions are off topic here.

Comment: Where would this question be better directed, then?

Comment: A site that's more open to discussion. If you want to stick with game development, try gamedev.net or reddit.com/r/gamedev. Or you can try some Python forums or something similar.